# Page Break After in IE is not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML page, in which I've different sections following which I've added div to separate each page while printing as below.

```
<div style="page-break-after:always"></div>
```

The problem is, if in first section data is less than the length of the page, **whole data is coming bottom of the first print page while printing**. I tried adding

```
<div style="page-break-after:always;clear:both;vertical-align:top;">&nbsp;</div>
```

But still its not working in IE browsers. Please help.

Comment: Presume you've set your doc type correctly?

Comment: it works fine in both of my firefox and IE. perhaps, which IE version you used for your testing?

Comment: What version of IE? Does it work properly on other browsers?

Comment: Doc type added is - 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

I have tested both IE7 and IE8.. Its not working..!! It works perfect on Firefox..